# will_paginate through ajax not working

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate 3.0.pre2 for pagination in rails 3

**Simple pagination that is without ajax its working fine but when i try to make links ajaxable they are not working.When i click on pagenumbers nothing happens.**

I have article and comment model.Comment model have polymorphic association with article and forum. For comments i am using pagination.

---

Articles Controller - where i have added required pagination code :

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @article.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
  @commentid = @article.id
  @commenttype = @article.class
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.js
  end
end
```

---

Comments Controller :

```
def index
  @comments = Comment.all..paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.js
  end
end


def show
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
```

---

application.js :

```
$("#comments_pagination .pagination a").live("click", function() {
  $.get("/articles/?"+this.href.split("?")[1], null, null, "script");
  return false
});
```

---

comments/index.html.haml :

```
%hr
%h2 Say something!
= form_for([@commentable,Comment.new], :remote => true) do |f|
  = f.label :commentcontent, "Comment here:"
  = f.text_field :commentcontent
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id
  = f.hidden_field :commentable_id, :value=> @commentid
  = f.hidden_field :commentable_type, :value=> @commenttype
  = f.submit "Add comment"

#addcomment
= render :template => 'comments/_pagelink'
```

---

_pagelink.html.haml :

```
#comments_pagination
= will_paginate(@comments,:renderer => RemoteLinkRenderer)
%h1 All comments
#comments
= render :partial=>@comments,:locals=>{:list=>true}
```

---

remote_link_renderer :

```
class RemoteLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer
    def link(text, target, attributes = {})
    attributes["data-remote"]   = true
    super
  end
end
```

---

index.js.erb:

```
$("#addcomment").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :template => 'comments/_pagelink') %>");
```